# How to avoid a blink when switching 2 GIF images display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

In [this animation of a incineration plant](http://www.energie-environnement.ch/component/content/article/132-fr-fr/la-maison/visites-dechets/1443?tmpl=component), when the visitor roll over a numbered button, the initial `img` is hidden and another `img` take his place. 
All images to be displayed are preloaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rep = HOTE + 'images/visites-dechets/uiom-kva-2/';

var imagesOver = new Array(
    'uiom-kva-1.gif',
    'uiom-kva-2.gif' 
/* others images...*/
);

window.onload = function() {
    preloadImages(rep, imagesOver);
    preloadFlag = true;
}

var prev_img = '';

function switchImg(sh, hi) {
    jQuery("#" + sh).show();
    jQuery("#" + hi).hide();
}
</script>
<div id="uiom" style="text-align: center;">
<img src="/images/visites-dechets/uiom-kva-2/uiom-kva.gif" id="img_usine" alt="" width="1000" height="600" usemap="#uiom-kva" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%;" /> 
<img src="/images/visites-dechets/uiom-kva-2/uiom-kva-1.gif" id="img_usine1" alt="" width="1000" height="600" usemap="#uiom-kva" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%; display: none;" />
<img src="/images/visites-dechets/uiom-kva-2/uiom-kva-2.gif" id="img_usine2" alt="" width="1000" height="600" usemap="#uiom-kva" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%; display: none;" /> 
<!-- others img... -->
<map id="uiom-kva" name="uiom-kva">
<area shape="circle" alt="" coords="101,484,22" href="#" id="btn-anim-1" onmouseover="switchImg('img_usine1', 'img_usine');return true" onmouseout="switchImg('img_usine', 'img_usine1');return true" />
<area shape="circle" alt="" coords="102,253,22" href="#" id="btn-anim-2" onmouseover="switchImg('img_usine2', 'img_usine');return true" onmouseout="switchImg('img_usine', 'img_usine2');return true" />
<!-- others areas... -->
</map>
</div>
```

When the user roll over a button for the first time, a blink is visible when the image is changed (in all browsers). Do you know how to avoid this. ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I think you need bigger areas for the triggering, dont be afraid to give it the whole section with background instead of tiny spot, it will improve user experience. For show/hiding you can try and swap the img.src http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805943/preventing-image-flicker-on-hover-when-replacing-it-with-another-image-css

Comment: Maybe instead you want to approach this utilizing `z-index` and having the images stacked on each other, then when you hover, fade out on the top image to show the image behind it.

Comment: I tried this solution and the blinks were gone; however there are some drawbacks : the gifs are played faster (?), the animations doesn't start always in their beginning, I'm forced to use absolute positionning
Thank you for your help yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut functions to produce a smoother result (instead of show and hide).

Comment: The images will need to be stacked (with position: absolute, relative, etc.) rather than static like in my case, in order to have a satisfing transition; otherwise, the img with fading out will stay on top meanwhile the img with fading in will be juste under...
Here is an implementation with fadeIn and fadeOut : http://www.energie-environnement.ch/component/content/article/132-fr-fr/la-maison/visites-dechets/1444?tmpl=component